# how to use fancybox with mvc3 and pictures stored in database

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, fancybox

```
<a href="@Url.Action("ShowPicture", "Pictures", new { id = Model.Pictures[i].PictureId })" title="lala" rel="image_group">
                <img src="@Url.Action("ShowPicture", "Pictures", new { id = Model.Pictures[i].PictureId })" width="200px" alt=""/>
            </a>
```

when i open link theh i can see picture

http://www.shrani.si/f/1N/77/2nh6icYN/2.png

but if i use fancybox then i usee

http://www.shrani.si/f/1g/Ka/4FZT4Kf6/1.png

i am reading picture from database. How to us efancybox with mvc and pictures stored in database

Puicture controller:

```
public ActionResult ShowPicture(int id)
        {
            ShowPictureModel model = new PictureManager().GetShowPictureModel(id);
            return File(model.Bytes, model.ContentType);
        }
```

Comment: weird - my company's firewall blocks those links as 'Adult Content'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set content type when binding fancybox -

```
$("a[rel='image_group']").fancybox({type: "image"});
```